# How to get my joined data into a column per month with multiple rows per month for each user?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a specific result but so far my attempts give an undesired result or an error.

```
SELECT u.Id 
      ,(SELECT c.Content FROM Contents c WHERE c.Month = '01' AND u.Id = c.Id) 'Month_1_Content'
      ,(SELECT c.Content FROM Contents c WHERE c.Month = '02' AND u.Id = c.Id) 'Month_2_Content'
      ,(SELECT c.Content FROM Contents c WHERE c.Month = '03' AND u.Id = c.Id) 'Month_3_Content'     
  FROM Users u;
```

Gives error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I also tried

```
SELECT u.Id 
      ,c.Content 'Month_1_Content'
      ,d.Content 'Month_2_Content'
      ,e.Content 'Month_3_Content'
  FROM Users u
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Content c 
    ON c.Month = '01' AND u.Id= c.Id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Content d 
    ON d.Month = '02' AND u.Id= d.Id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Content e 
    ON e.Month = '03' AND u.Id= e.Id
```

But this query does not return the aimed for result.

**Query Result that I want to get**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
   Id   | Month_1_Content | Month_2_Content | Month_3_Content
-------------------------------------------------------------
 scott  |    01_scott_1   |    02_scott_1   |
 scott  |    01_scott_2   |                 |
 tiger  |                 |    02_tiger_1   |    03_tiger_1   
 tiger  |                 |    02_tiger_2   |    03_tiger_2  
 tiger  |                 |                 |    03_tiger_3   
 cat    |                 |                 | 
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Sample data

**Table Users**

```
Users
-----
 Id
-----
scott
tiger
cat
-----
```

**Table Contents**

```
Contents
--------------------------------------
Month |   Id   | Sequence |  Content
--------------------------------------
01    | scott  |    1     | 01_scott_1
01    | scott  |    2     | 01_scott_2
02    | scott  |    1     | 02_scott_1
02    | tiger  |    1     | 02_tiger_1
02    | tiger  |    2     | 02_tiger_2
03    | tiger  |    1     | 03_tiger_1
03    | tiger  |    2     | 03_tiger_2
03    | tiger  |    3     | 03_tiger_3
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: Your desired result looks like the output of a crosstab query. In TSQL the PIVOT command is used to obtain such results.

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you. You clearly have more than 1 row for each user for a specific month, so in such cases what value(s) are you expecting?

Comment: Looks like you ned to use `Id, Sequence` as grouping columns and pivot the `Content` values into columns per  `Month`

Comment: your inner query might be returning more then one rows. (SELECT c.Content FROM Contents c WHERE c.Month = '01' AND u.Id = c.Id) ideally aggregating/distincting data should be able to resolve the issue (SELECT distinct(c.Content) FROM Contents c WHERE c.Month = '01' AND u.Id = c.Id) something like that. if you want further help on this, please put in the sample input and output data

Comment: @NNM I've put the structure of tables and the result I want.

Comment: I know you've gotten an answer but you may want to look in full outer joins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your immediate problem is the rather clear error message `Subquery returned more than 1 value` which quite obviously means you have a subquery that is returning multiple values.

You could make it return a single value, using `TOP 1` or some form of aggregation, but that will not get you your desired results.

What you actually want is to pivot on `Id, Sequence` and return `Content` per `Month`.

You can use the `PIVOT` operator, but the best way to pivot is to manually pivot using `MAX(CASE`

```sql
SELECT
  u.Id ,
  c.*
FROM Users u
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
      MAX(CASE WHEN c.Month = '01' THEN c.Content END) AS Month_1_Content,
      MAX(CASE WHEN c.Month = '02' THEN c.Content END) AS Month_2_Content,
      MAX(CASE WHEN c.Month = '03' THEN c.Content END) AS Month_3_Content
    FROM Content c 
    WHERE u.Id = c.Id
    GROUP BY
      c.Sequence
) c;
```

`APPLY` is often a good way to pre-aggregate, although you can do this with normal joins also

```sql
SELECT
  u.id,
  c.*
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      c.id,
      MAX(CASE WHEN c.Month = '01' THEN c.Content END) AS Month_1_Content,
      MAX(CASE WHEN c.Month = '02' THEN c.Content END) AS Month_2_Content,
      MAX(CASE WHEN c.Month = '03' THEN c.Content END) AS Month_3_Content
    FROM Content c
    GROUP BY
      c.Id,
      c.Sequence
) c ON u.Id = c.Id;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/Cu8Pz7Cx)

Comment: You are missing `cat` in your sample data and then the second query needs adjusting https://dbfiddle.uk/Cer6cAHA

Comment: @Martin Smith You are right. But I can solve it by putting u.Id next by 'Select'

Comment: @Charlieface Your answer is working Goooood.   Thank you very much.  You are my angel.  Merry Christmas!!

Answer (score -2):

A simple answer to your question (how to avoid the error), but you may have underlying data issues that make the following solution ineffective. That's up to you to determine.

Add "TOP 1" to your subqueries to ensure only one result is returned for each.

```
SELECT u.Id 
      ,(SELECT TOP 1 c.Content FROM Contents c WHERE c.Month = '01' AND u.Id = c.Id) 'Month_1_Content'
      ,(SELECT TOP 1 c.Content FROM Contents c WHERE c.Month = '02' AND u.Id = c.Id) 'Month_2_Content'
      ,(SELECT TOP 1 c.Content FROM Contents c WHERE c.Month = '03' AND u.Id = c.Id) 'Month_3_Content'     
  FROM Users u;
```

Comment: I didn't say I downvoted this? But I agree, a solution that introduces another flaw is not a solution. It's *not* speculation, I can see your SQL, and I can see that the `TOP` has no `ORDER BY`.

Comment: But you don't know that it does. Only the OP knows if the result that Top 1 produces here will be incorrect. It could be the case that all the results have the same value for c.Content. Again, only the OP knows. Stay on topic of the question asked.

Comment: I do *know* it does, as `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` returns arbitrary rows. That is a *fact*.

Comment: Yes, but all of the rows might have the same c.Content value. Lord. Only the OP knows.

Comment: They have told us what they want. And this isn't it. But it is hidden in the "Table structure and the result I'm expecting" link (Edit: now in the question as text)

Comment: @John Joseph   thanx, but I need to get all the rows.

Comment: Then you need to rephrase your question. A lot. You need to accomplish this with a join. Your question should be phrased more like, "How do I join two tables to return all rows from both tables?" Or look at the hundreds of other times that was asked.

Comment: @John Joseph Thank you for your advise. I will do next time.

Comment: Not *next* time, @TOP. ; **this** time.

Comment: @Thom A  I've accepted your proposal. Thank you.

Comment: TBH the suggested title "improvement" was supplied by someone that didn't follow what you were asking so not really accurate either but thanks for responding to all the requests for improvements